# Polymer paper-toggle-button

Tags: javascript, jquery, toggle, polymer

Polymer has a paper item called paper-toggle-button. My question is, how can I make a action for this element (if it's on, or off) using Jquery?

I did something that is working properly on computers, but working pretty bad on mobile !

```
$('#paper_toggle_button').click(function(){
    if($(this).hasClass('off')){
        $(this).addClass('on');
        $(this).removeClass('off');
        $(this).attr('aria-pressed','true');
        $('#clock').css('display','none');//action that must do
        $('#clock2').fadeIn('slow');//action that must do
    } else{
        $(this).addClass('off');
        $(this).removeClass('on');
        $(this).attr('aria-pressed','false');
        $('#clock').fadeIn('slow');//action that must do
        $('#clock2').css('display','none');//action that must do
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

i don't know about using jquery but with polymer you could just use the on-tap attribute.

```
<paper-toggle-button on-tap="{{doStuff}}"></paper-toggle-button>
```

this would call the doStuff function. (keep in mind this must happen inside a template. like inside a custom element)

and with js you could

```
var button = document.querySelector('#paper_toggle_button');
button.addEventListener('click', function () {
  if (button.checked) {
    // turn something off
  } else {
    // turn something on
  }
});
```

hope it helps